# mariaDB extract only the digits from {"user":"128"}

Tags: regex, mariadb

From the string `{"user":"128"}`, expected only `128`.

Could also be `{"user":"8"}` or `{"user":"12"}` or `{"user":"128798"}`

In this fiddle [example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/LVCvymt2uyKrz4sjbEzUC/1) the matched value should be `3`

> Schema:
>
> ```sql
> CREATE TABLE test1 (
>   id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   userid INT(11),
>   PRIMARY KEY (id)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO test1(userid)
> VALUES
> ('126'),
> ('2457'),
> ('3'),
> ('40');
>
> CREATE TABLE test2 (
>   id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   code VARCHAR(1024),
>   PRIMARY KEY (id)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO test2(code)
> VALUES
> ('{"user":"128"}'),
> ('{"user":"2459"}'),
> ('{"user":"3"}'),
> ('{"user":"46"}');
> ```
>
> Query:
>
> ```sql
> (SELECT sub.`userid`, rev.`code` REGEXP '[0-9]'
> FROM `test1` AS sub, `test2` AS rev
> WHERE sub.`userid`= rev.`code` 
> )
> ```

Have tried `REGEXP '[0-9]'` and also `'[[:digit:]]'` but no luck.

I have also tried `concat ('',value * 1) = value` or `concat(value * 1) = value`

SOLUTION: [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/LVCvymt2uyKrz4sjbEzUC/3)

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using please

Comment: Using MariaDB 10.6.4

Comment: *In this fiddle example the matched value should be 3* ??? Why? look at your fiddle data carefully.

Comment: Why is it that one value doesn't conform to the `{"user": "id"}` format while all the others do? Can this data be normalised so all the values are using the same structure?

Comment: Sorry I missed that. Edited and now normalised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REGEXP will return 0 or 1 if the regexp matches the string.

You should have a look to 'regexp_substr'
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-substr

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(code, '"[0-9]+"') from test2
```

This works for me, after selecting MySQL 8 version in your fiddler.
it returns :

```
"128"
"2459"
null
"46"
```

or

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(code, '[0-9]+') from test2
```

if you want 3 instead of null for "k3"

[akina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10138734/akina) suggestion of using JSON_EXTRACT is way better, but does require that you redefine the column as a JSON datatype from VARCHAR.

Comment: But looking at the schema, the field is defined as a VARCHAR() :)

Comment: This is exactly how it is defined in the table I am trying to match

Comment: Does MariaDB have datatype JSON? Although it is shown, when selected turns to Longtext. Will it work as expected if selected? According to Rick James [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/245357/json-field-saves-as-longtext-datatype)

Comment: ```select REGEXP_SUBSTR(code, '[0-9]+') from test2``` did the job for the moment. [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/LVCvymt2uyKrz4sjbEzUC/3). Will also check @Akina JSON. Thank you all.

Comment: And how would it be in case of ```'{"user":"128.3"}'``` or ```'{"user":"2459.45"}'```

Comment: select REGEXP_SUBSTR(code, '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+') from test2

but that would be weird to have a decimal as a userID

Answer (score 0):

Use the function REGEXP_SUBSTR:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT  REGEXP_SUBSTR('{"user":"128"}', '\\d+');
+-----------------------------------------+
| REGEXP_SUBSTR('{"user":"128"}', '\\d+') |
+-----------------------------------------+
| 128                                     |
+-----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```